# Firefox download inside IFrame issue

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have this html:

```
<iframe id='if1' scrolling='no' style='border:none;scroll:none;' sandbox='allow-forms allow-scripts' src='http://downloadfiles.example/down1.html'></iframe>
```

In the webpage ( **external webpage** I don't have access to edit it ):

> http://downloadfiles.example/down1.html

I have a **download button** ( **direct download link** )

On **Firefox** If I click the download button the download don't starts.

So how to fix this issue and make the download starts ?

Thanks.